# The neovim plugin for tpope/vim-surround isn't working in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vim-plugin, neovim

I'm looking for thoughts on how I've configured this differently this time.

I have been using this plug in previous versions.

I have the init.vim correctly configured (the plugin works with nvim) from the console.

I'm using the dein plugin manager.

I know the init.vim is being loaded from vscode.

I'm just not getting the surround functionality in vscode.

What's even stranger is it's working on my old laptop just fine, AFAIK I've copied all the settings.

The only difference is the the version of NeoVim installed, but as I mentioned - the plugin works from the console.

Answer (score 0):

Leave the path to the `init.vim` blank.  Still not sure why this works on the old laptop with this value ...